# Mapping of CSS and JS files

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

My project works well with "/" pattern. But when i connect js and css it doesnt work as well as want, 'cause dispatcher servlet doesnt map css and js. When I specified ".htm" pattern css and js work, but all my pages(e.g. "/polls/categories") dont work.
This is my web.xml file.

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And dispatcher-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="1"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Not clear what the question is.

Comment: I would think that you want web resources to be EXCLUDED from being mapped :/

Answer (score 0):

Add this bit to your dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

You should put static resources inside this location :

```
PROJECT_ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources
```

And then access them from your views like this (example for css):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="${webappRoot}/resources/css/style.css" />" type="text/css">
```

Answer update (dispatcher-servlet.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

Not sure what are you trying to accomplish with this bit here:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
```

But if you're trying to create controller all you have to do is to add annotation to your class like this :

```
@Controller
class ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping{
....body omitted..
}
```

**Update 2**

If this doesn't help, why do the things hard way. Download spring tool suite (easy to google). With this tool you can just create new spring project and the tool will create appropriate structure with valid configurations. And check this one out, really short and concise :

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/MasteringSpringMVC3.pdf?raw=true

Comment: I put files to the resource folder, but Tomcat generates error "Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources]"